# What is Coded Feature in Auto Encoder ? Is there any formula used to calculate the Coded Feature?

Tags: keras

I am working on AutoCoder. I have drawn graphs for Input values and Reconstructed values using Matplotlib. How to draw graph for Coded Features and what is Coded Features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An auto-encoder is a type of neural network where you combine an encoder and a decoder. Typically the output of the encoder has less parameters than the input and the decoder takes this reduced number of parameters to recreate the original input as closely as possible. You can think of the output of the encoder (also named 'latent vector') as a lossy compression of the input. There are however multiple other use-cases and types of auto-encoders. You can read more about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) and [this blogpost on towardsdatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/auto-encoder-what-is-it-and-what-is-it-used-for-part-1-3e5c6f017726) also gives a very good explanation with examples.

If you want an explanation on how to draw graphs, you will need to give us more information on your input dataset and maybe show us your graphs of the input and output, because I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am working on AutoEncoder. I draw graphs for loss function and reconstructed value. Now I want to draw a graph for the intermediate layer? Can you please suggest me how to draw graphs for intermediate layer

Comment: Again, I don't know what you mean with "graphs for intermediate layer"... Do you want to see some kind of loss? In that case I don't think it's possible because you don't have any ground-thruth for the intermediate layer and therefore no way of calculating the loss for this layer (independent from the loss of the output layer).

Comment: If you show me the architecture of your neural network I might be able to help you better

Comment: Input Dataset -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py/master/examples/Bio/bio_100Hz.csv

Comment: Used the ECG Data set

Comment: Got the output  Test Loss: 2.43%
Accuracy is  97.57%
Compression ratio for the ECG Dataset is 40.0

Comment: Drawn Graph for Loss function Successfully

Comment: My question is How can I visualize the output of an intermediate layer in Keras Autoencoder ?

Comment: Based on your code it looks like you are converting 1 parameter to 50 parameters in the middle layer, this is not compression. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: I referred the site to obtain the output of an intermediate layer?

Comment: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

Comment: Thank you got the output